# Discord.json How can I resize avatar in an embed?

Tags: node.js, json, discord, discord.js

```
    {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0x333333)
        .setAuthor(member.username)
        .setTitle('Avatar')
        .setImage(member.avatarURL(), 500, 500);
        message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
    }
})
```

Hi! This is my code. I'm basically trying to prind a said user's avatar. I'm having some problems at resizing that user's avatar. What I would like is to make it bigger when sending it back. How can one do that with discord.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all so you know the next time: the library is called **discord.js**, not discord.json.

For your problem, you can add **?size=256** after `member.avatarURL()` for the picture to appear bigger.

Here's an image explaining what I mean by "?size=256". Hope that helps.

[Picture showing ?size=256](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXEM5.png)

Comment: Doing this returns compilation error since ? is not recognised.
.setImage(member.avatarURL(), ?size=256)
I don't think this is relevant towards coding

Comment: try doing ```setImage(`${member.avatarURL()}?size=256`)``` and I think it'll work (I did it on my own bot)

Answer (score 1):

You might have gotten your answer by now but this might work

`.setImage(member.avatarURL({size: 256}))`